# Solving $\dot{x}(t) = \sqrt{\dot{x}(0)^2 - k[x(t)^2 - x(0)^2]}$ for $x(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\dot{x}$ mean $\frac{d}{dt}x$.
When doing a (one dimensional) physics problem where one were supposed to find the velocity $v_x(t)$ I arrived at the solution
$$v_x(t) = \sqrt{v_0^2 - k(x^2 - x_0^2}).$$
Where $v_0 = v_x(t=0)$ and $x_0 = x(t=0)$ are known. One could infer this from knowing the acceleration as a function of the position $x$.

I became curious if one could find the position as a function of time, $x(t)$, from this equation since to me it seems to be a differential equation of the form
$$\dot{x}(t) = \sqrt{\dot{x}(0)^2 - k[x(t)^2 - x(0)^2]}$$ which I guess could be written as $$\dot{x}(t)^2 - \dot{x}(0)^2 = -k[x(t)^2 - x(0)^2]$$
But since I have a very limited knowledge of differential equations (I think I've only done some linear ones before) I don't know if this is possible to solve for $x(t)$ and in that case how?

Comment: You are solving $\ddot x+kx=0$ which is a harmonic oscillator with well-known solutions. (The first-order equation has one or two non-zero constant solutions that are not covered by the second order equation, but I suspectz you did start out from the second order equation?)

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah, yes that is an excellent observation! My book has gone through such equations so that solves my problem. I would accept your comment as an answer if possible.